# Clickhouse aggregation with map

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have this SQL query for clickhouse

```
SELECT
    nested.query,
    map(toStartOfInterval(nested.time, INTERVAL 1 DAY), sumMap(map(nested.method, nested.count))) as time_method_map,
    sumMap(map(nested.ip, nested.count)),
    sumMap(map(nested.lang, nested.count))
FROM
    (SELECT
         query,
         method,
         count() AS count,
         ip,
         lang,
         time
     FROM
         calls
     GROUP BY
         query,
         method,
         ip,
         lang,
         time) AS nested
GROUP BY
    nested.query
```

I need to group table only by `nested.query`, but top map requires group by time too.
If i add aggregation i get something like

```
Query TimeMethodMap
a     {27:{'a':1}}
a     {28:{'a':1}}
a     {28:{'c':2}}
b     {28:{'a':1}}
```

what i want to achieve

```
Query TimeMethodMap
a     {27:[{'a':1}], 28:[{'a':1}, {'c':2}]}
b     {28:[{'a':1}]}
```